# I recently reset my Galaxy S5 to manufacture and lost all contacts, Can I retrieve my contacts back

Tags: samsung

Can I retrieve my contacts back to my device .I recently reset my device to the manufacturers original.

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth checking to see if google automatically synced your contacts to your gmail account. If so, they are recoverable if not they’re toast.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to backup your contacts is to sync them with your google account. If you have done so then you can recover them without any issue, if not then unfortunately you won't get any contacts back.